# @XmlRootElement to String

Tags: rest, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a class with the annotation @XmlRootElement to interact with some REST services, usually I create a javax.ws.rs.client.Entity based on this object and put it in the request body.
Now one of the services doesn't require the xml object in the body but requires a xml post parameter with the utf-8 encoding of the xml object.
How can I obtain the "string xml version" of the object annotated with @XmlRootElement to use it in the parameters?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. You just need to convert a @XmlRootElement annotated class to a String and pass it from your client to an existing Service?

Answer (score 11):

Use a JAXB [Marshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) to convert your object to a XML-String:

```java
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Something.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(something, out);
String xml = out.toString();
```